# How to create meta annotations on field level?

Tags: java, annotations, hibernate-annotations

I have this hibernate class with annotations:

```
@Entity
public class SimponsFamily{

  @Id
  @TableGenerator(name = ENTITY_ID_GENERATOR,
                table = ENTITY_ID_GENERATOR_TABLE,
                pkColumnName = ENTITY_ID_GENERATOR_TABLE_PK_COLUMN_NAME,
                valueColumnName = ENTITY_ID_GENERATOR_TABLE_VALUE_COLUMN_NAME)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = ENTITY_ID_GENERATOR)
  private long id;

  ...
}
```

Since I don´t won´t to annotate every *id* field of my classes that way, I tried to create a custom anotation:

```
@TableGenerator(name = ENTITY_ID_GENERATOR,
            table = ENTITY_ID_GENERATOR_TABLE,
            pkColumnName = ENTITY_ID_GENERATOR_TABLE_PK_COLUMN_NAME,
            valueColumnName = ENTITY_ID_GENERATOR_TABLE_VALUE_COLUMN_NAME)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface EntityId {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = ENTITY_ID_GENERATOR)
    public int generator() default 0;

    @Id
    public long id() default 0;
}
```

so that I can use this annotation in my class:

```
 @Entity
 public class SimponsFamily{


 @EntityId
 private long id;

  ...
}
```

I do have to write the `@Id` and the `@GeneratedValue` annotions on field level since they do not support the TYPE RetentionPolicy. This solutions seems to work.

My questions:

- How are the field level annotations in my custom annotations(and values) *transferred* to my usage of EntityId annotation?
- What about the default values which I set in my custom annotation, are they used since I do not specify attributes at the usage?
- It is a preferred way to use annotations on field level in annotations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I can aswer your third question.

One common way to do what you want (avoid duplicating ID mapping) is to create a common superclass that holds the annotated `id` and `version` (for optimistic locking) fields, and then have all persistent objects extend this superclass. 
To ensure the superclass is not considered an Entity on its own, it must be annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`.

Here is a sample (sorry for typos, I don't have an IDE at hand right now) :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class PersistentObject {

    @Id // Put all your ID mapping here
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

}

@Entity
public class SimpsonsFamily extends PersistentObject {        
    // Other SimpsonFamily-specific fields here, with their mappings    
}
```

Comment: My hope was that I can avoid a superclass, but maybe this is the way to go... maybe my question is more a general annotation issue rather a hibernate problem. Thx anyway!