# Hibernate Sequence Id Specification

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sequence, global

I have this annotation to specify a sequence id:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parametro_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "parametro_seq_gen", sequenceName = "PARAMETROS_SQ",
      allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
```

I find it very verbose to repeat on all my entities.

Is there any way to create a custom annotation or something ? I want to specify only the **sequence name**.

Comment: Some JPA providers allow "meta-annotations" like you suggest http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/annotations.html#meta_annotations  Does your JPA provider?

Comment: Something like that could be useful. Is it possible to add a parameter to the meta annotation ? Because i need to send the sequence name. Looking after your comment , i found something similar on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810269/how-to-create-meta-annotations-on-field-level

Answer (score 3):

That's easy!

Just create a `package-info.java` where entities are stored and provide the global `@GenericGenerator` there:

```
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "pooled",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "sequence"),
        @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
        @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "5"),
    }
)
package com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.identifier.globalsequence;
```

Then your entities can share the `pooled` generic generator as follows:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "pooled")
    private Long id;
}

@Entity(name = "Announcement")
public class Announcement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "pooled")
    private Long id;
}
```

You need to use `@GenericGenerator` since `@SequenceGenerator` is not applicable to packages.

That's it!

Comment: thanks Vlad, sorry maybe i didn't specify my situation correctly. All entities have different sequences, one per each entitiy. But for all of them i want the same properties, like allocation size and inital value. I was looking for some way to only annotate: @Sequence("PARAMETROS_SQ"), @Sequence("CONSULTAS_SQ").

Comment: That will not work. You either reuse the same definition or provide a new one. There's no way you can reuse a base definition and still override it on a per entity basis.

Comment: i was thinking something like writing a custom annotation? the idea is to facilitate the developers to specify the sequence. Is something like this possible ?

Comment: An example of writing a sequence generator : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567375/sequencestylegenerator-how-to-to-use-prefix-instead-of-suffixe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with the custom annotation or something else in the hack way, but what I suggest is to using the live template ( I'm using IDEA )
[image]

[image]